# Laravel how to compare the duration with the timer

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I have a table where i save jobs for employes, also there is a column called duration. I want when duration end do display an alert or some other event.I am using laravel and vue for this. This is the jobs table

```
                id: 3
           job_name: Rep 01
    job_description: ASA
         start_date: 2022-10-12 10:39:00
           end_date: 2022-10-14 10:39:00
           duration: 01:00
        client_name: Katell Rollins
client_phone_number: +1 (401) 558-7758
      client_adress: ----
      job_completed: 0
         created_at: 2022-10-12 08:39:21
         updated_at: 2022-10-12 08:39:21
```

Answer (score 0):

Watch this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q_fLx2KcoYA).
Watch from 19:40 if you want to get right into the code you want.
this might help

Comment: I dont have countdown time. Just have static number